Android App help, failing to intercept SMS Messages
I am developing an application and one of it's functions is to intercept outgoing text messages. I have setup a Broadcast Receiver java class and set logging for everything. When I run the application I can see from the logging that the Broadcast Receiver is triggered and the logged message "Outgoing SMS interception started" is logged. See class code:
package com.site.app;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;


public class OutgoingSmsInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "com.site.app/interceptor";
    private static final String TAG = "OutgoingSmsInterceptor";

    public static void registerWith(FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                        if (call.method.equals("interceptOutgoingMessages")) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Outgoing SMS interception started");
                            result.success(null);
                        } else {
                            result.notImplemented();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Broadcast received: " + intent.getAction());
        Log.d(TAG, "Received broadcast");
        try {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Intercepting outgoing SMS");
                String recipient = intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
                String body = intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT");

                if (recipient != null && body != null) {
                    DTGMessage dtgMessage = new DTGMessage(recipient, body);
                    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                    databaseHelper.insertMessage(dtgMessage);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Message intercepted and saved to database");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error intercepting outgoing SMS", e);
        }
    }
}

So the method call is working and triggering the BroadcastReceiver but the onReceive is never triggered when a text message is sent. I have the intent filter set in the AndroidManifest.xml. (see code)
  <!-- Broadcast Receiver for intercepting SMS -->
        <receiver android:name=".OutgoingSmsInterceptor"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

And permissions are configured as well
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

I have been over this a million times in the last couple days and I can't seem to figure out where I am failing. If anyone has successfully intercepted outgoing SMS messages on Android I would love to hear from you.
My expectation is that the BroadcastReceiver would trigger and then when I send a sms message that the onReceive would trigger. it is the second part I am not getting and I believe I am missing a step somewhere.

What you're attempting is not possible in Android. The "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" action does not exist in the SDK, and there is no general system broadcast when an SMS is sent. The only way to "intercept" messages is to be the default SMS app and have users send them through your app somehow, but even then, any app using SmsManager directly would essentially bypass yours.
